# Codeigniter reusable sections

Tags: codeigniter, code-reuse, codeigniter-2

I have a table of data from a database that I want to display on various pages of my website. Ideally, i would like to just have an include or something that will go off and get the data, and return the html table. The html and data will be identical everytime I need to use this.

I wanted to know the best way of doing this

Thanks

EDIT

If this helps, something similar to a Django "inclusion" custom tag...for any django developers reading

Comment: You could create a view containing that html which you could include in other views.(if you are certain that the data will be the same every time, you can create the html before putting the site live and just include the view)

Comment: The data itself may not be the same, but the format for the data will be, no matter which page it is put on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is one thing that worked for me, but its definitely not perfect.

I created a view in which made a call to the model getting the data then put the data into a table. This way, I only have to include this view to put the table anywhere.

I understand this completely ruins the point of having a MVC framework, but hopefully it demonstrates what I want to do...and it works

Comment: You could have rendered the view as a child and passed the parameters which included you data to that child. this way no direct call to DB will be made via view.

Answer (score 1):

```
 you need to pass the variable $data to the view method.

This is your code:

function load_my_view(){  
    $this->load->model('my_table');
    $data['my_results'] = $this->my_table->my_data();
    $this->load->view('my_view');
}

Please change it to this in order to load the $data into the view:

function load_my_view(){  
    $this->load->model('my_table');
    $data['my_results'] = $this->my_table->my_data();
    $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function in a model to fetch the data you need.  Your controller calls the model function and sends the returned information to a view.  You don't need to use traditional php includes with Codeigniter.  I recommend a review of the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).  It's very good and will tell you all the basic stuff you need to know to develop with CI.  But to get you started, you watn to use [Models, Views, and Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html).  Your url will tell CI what controller and function inside that controller to run.  If your url is

http://www.example.com/my_controller/load_my_view

Then CI will do what is inside the load_my_view function in the my_controller controller.  function load_my_view in turn instantiates a model "my_table" and runs a database query, returns information that the controller sends to the view.  A basic example follows:

Your model

```
class my_table extends CI_Model{
    function my_data(){
        $this->db->select('column_1,column_2,column_3');
        $this->db->from('my_table');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
          $result = $query->result();
        }
        else{
          $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }


}
```

Your controller

```
class my_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function load_my_view(){  
        $this->load->model('my_table');
        $data['my_results'] = $this->my_table->my_data();
        $this->load->view('my_view');
    }
```

}

Your View

```
<ul id = "my_db_results">

    <?php foreach($my_results as $result):?>
         <li><?php echo $result->column_1." : ".$result->column_2." ( ".$result->column_3." )";?></li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for th reply. I do understand the mvc, my point was that I have a block of data (in my case, just an ordered table) that I am wanting to use in several places. So instead of having to do all that stuff and load it into the view, if there was something I could do to just say "get that table and put it here"...if that makes sense

Comment: I guess caching might be your answer then, as bensiu suggests, unless you are up to creating an image file on the fly and inserting that wherever you need the table after the initial get request.

Comment: Would caching update the table every time though? Sure there is something you can do to make a reusable section of code/data...

Comment: You could make the html table you describe into a string and store it in a special db table as that string. If your table is as static as you say, this would only mean one db call per page load.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good oportunity to use cache: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html